# "How's that sound?" in Mandarin

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-requests, phrase-request

What would be an appropriate way to end a sentence after making a suggestion/offering an opinion in anticipation of the response? For instance, while talking to a friend, I share something with them followed by "how's that sound to you?" or "what do you think?" in order to elicit some sort of reply pertaining to my previous statement.

Examples for clarity:

1) We should try bubble tea sometime. **Thoughts?**

2) Rabbits are much cuter than cats. **What do you think?**

3) I will pick up your medication at 6:00. **How's that?**

4) (Random sentence in Mandarin + unsure how it sounds in context). **How was that?** Was it okay for this situation?

I am aware of **好吗**，**对吗**，**是不是**。Yet these seem to be used primarily for the purpose of affirmation. I also know **怎么样** is appropriate for asking "how was it/how have you been". Might **吧** fit in here at all (possibly in the form of a question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like "what do you think?" you can say:
你覺得呢？
你覺得如何？
Or simply 如何？

You can also end a sentence with 對吧 or 是吧, that's a bit like "right?", "Isn't it?". But this isn't as explicit in asking for a response, just a confirmation, with 吧 indicating that you're somewhat unsure.

Comment: Would 這個句子對吧 be okay to use after I say something in Mandarin as a way to check if it was used correctly? Basically situation #4 above

Comment: You can say that in the case where you think it's right, but you just want to make sure. If you don't know if it's right just use 嗎. Another way you can express this is using 可以嗎？ 這樣可以(說)嗎？ Actually, 可以嗎？ can also be used in question 1 and 3, where you're asking for approval or confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

The most common sentence is "怎么样？“ in Chinese, which is "what do you think?". It can be added after any suggestion sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think 你覺得怎麼樣 or 你覺得如何 is sufficient to ask for opinion of others after a person suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would say

你認爲怎麽樣？

or

你認爲該怎麽做？

if it requires action.

Or really short...

你認爲呢？

Comment: If I wanted to use 怎麽樣 for situation #4 above, that is, double-checking whether a certain sentence/phrase made sense in the context of a conversation, would that be okay? For example, 【*Mandarin phrase*，  這個句子怎麽樣？】

Comment: Yes, that would work. It translates roughly as "what about this sentence?"

Answer (score 1):

Using simple statement, I'll recommend:

1.怎樣? or 怎麼樣? How's that? OK or not?   (It's like talking between friends)

2.如何? similar like "Is it sounds good?" "Is it okay?"  (It's a little bit more polite then 1st)

3.(你/妳)覺得呢?  How did you feel/sound? (think/feel) (It's more polite then 2nd, consider his/her feeling and then asking for the answer.)

4.你認爲呢？ What do you think? (It's more like asking for an opinion or view to make a decision.)

All of these have felling asking for yes or no. And all of these are Colloquial.

Comment: Is there a difference between 怎麽樣 and 怎樣？

Comment: There is no essential difference, its a little bit like between "kind of" and "kinda", and without informal issue, both of it is like colloquial.